# Gsap not working properly with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, gsap

I am writing app in nuxt.js with ssr rendering. I have a problem with gsap. I am using typescript and when I am trying to use timeline.staggerTo() method I am getting error that property staggerTo() does not exists on TimelineMax type.

How I am using gsap:
I've installed it with yarn add gsap
then i've imported TimelineMax from "gsap"

that's all

to() works for example but staggerTo / from no. Probably there is no definition for that. Does anybody knows what I can make in order to fix / workaround it ?

Thanks a lot for help <3

some code

```
import Vue from "vue";

import { TweenMax, gsap, TimelineMax } from "gsap";

export default Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    const timeline = new TimelineMax();
    timeline
      .fromTo(
        ".header__subtitle",
        1,
        { opacity: 0, translateY: -30 },
        { opacity: 1, translateY: 0 }
      )
      .staggerFrom(); //Property 'staggerFrom' does not exist on type 'TimelineMax'.Vetur(2339)
  }
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work here?

Comment: My app won't compile because I am getting error when using staggerTo that it doesn't exists

Comment: Which version of GSAP are you using? I don't think those methods exist in v3?

Comment: I'am using 3.3.4

Comment: I can't seem to find those methods on the GSAP Docs https://greensock.com/docs/search/stagger

Comment: I have read similar problem on gsap forum but there wasn't universal solution. This issue was from February so i thought that maybe something have changed until now. Pretty sad if no ;D

Comment: oh... ok. Maybe there is something else in v3. I am confused now. I am using gsap for 2 hours now andmaybe i dont know about something ;D Thanks a lot. I will read docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're not using a version of GSAP 3 that has the latest Typescript declarations. The Typescript definitions included with GSAP got a major improvement in version 3.3. **Do not use the @types declarations** as they are extremely old and outdated. I think that upgrading your GSAP version and uninstalling a @types declarations should fix your issue because TimelineMax is a convenience for .timeline() in GSAP 3.

With that being said, we at GreenSock recommend that you use [GSAP 3 formatting](https://greensock.com/3-migration). I would format your code like so:

```js
import Vue from "vue";

import { gsap } from "gsap";

export default Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    const timeline = gsap.timeline()
      .fromTo(".header__subtitle", {
        opacity: 0,
        translateY: -30
      }, {
        duration: 1, 
        opacity: 1, 
        translateY: 0,
        stagger: 0.2
      })
  }
});
```

For more info about staggers, check out [the stagger documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Staggers).

FYI you're more likely to get a faster response over [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in order to create stagger just add
{stagger: 0.1} in fromVars/ toVars

have a nice day :)

Comment: Note that the stagger property should be included in the last parameter of a tween (the only one for .from() and .to() but the second one for a .fromTo()).